# .find() is not a function in mongoose + nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to find by id and getting bankApp.find is not a function.

This is my schema

```
import {model, Schema} from "mongoose";

const StatusResponse = new Schema({
   uniqueKey: {type: String, trim: true, unique: true},
   leadKey: {type: String, trim: true, unique: true},
   riskStatus: {type: String},
}, {timestamps: true});

module.exports.statusModel = model('Status', StatusResponse);
```

This is my code where I am using .find()

```
const StatusResponse = require('../../models/StatusResponse');

exports.createApplication = async (req, reply) => {

   const data = req.body;

   let response = StatusResponse.statusModel(data);
   await response.save();
   let find = await response.find({"_id": "aaa"}).;
}
```

.save is running perfectly fine. But not able to figure out why .find() is not running.

Answer (score 0):

Why `response.find()` ??

it should be a `Model.find();` like below

```
let find = await statusModel.find({"_id": "aaa"}).;
```

Comment: my bad.Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 StatusResponse.find({"id":"aaa"})
```

and you are saving your data in worng way, you can use

```
 const response = new StatusResponse(data); 
 await response.save();
```